# Running code on all files from a folder, only works for one

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to run this code on all files from a specific folder. This code works fines from one file.

Someone could please help me?

```
Sub SplitWorkbook()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim DisplayStatusBar As Boolean
    DisplayStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Dim NewFileName As String
        Application.StatusBar = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count & _
                                " Remaining Sheets"
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count <> 1 Then
            NewFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsm" _
                          'Macro-Enabled
            ' NewFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx" _
            'Not Macro-Enabled
            ws.Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFileName, _
                                  FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
            ' ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFileName, _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Else
            NewFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsm"
            ' NewFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
            ws.Name = "Sheet1"
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = DisplayStatusBar
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You're iterating *worksheets*, not files in a folder. Have you tried anything? You'll want to take a `Workbook` parameter and use that parameter in place of `ThisWorkbook`. Then you'll want a procedure that iterates files in a folder and opens one workbook at a time and invokes this procedure, passing in the workbook object.

Comment: You can do a search for "loop through files in a folder", there are a number of questions on SO, that have viable answers.

Comment: Thank you, Mathieu... Yeah, I'm strulling there... I already tried search "loop through files", but no code worked as expected. Since I'm totally new to the subject I prefer not to put my "adventures"